# 3g modem dialup prevented by MSDTC corruption

Tags: corruption, msdtc, dialup, reconnect

We have ~50 machines which connect via a 3G modem from [Option](http://www.option.com/) (either the [Globesurfer Icon](http://www.option.com/en/support/software-download/usb-modems/icon/), [Icon 401](http://www.option.com/en/support/software-download/usb-modems/icon401/) or [Icon 7.2](http://www.option.com/en/support/software-download/usb-modems/icon7-2/)) to the network, for some reason from the [telco](http://www.mtnns.co.za/) they will be dropped (signal issue, tower, butterfly flapping it's wings - the telco is not much help here). After the drop, the machines fail to reconnect.

The error message that comes up is `Cannot load phonebook. Error 1722 RPC is unavailable` and checking the event log the following issue us listed there:
  `Event Type:  Error

  Event Source: MSDTC Client

  Event Category:   (10)

  Event ID: 4427

  Date:     2009/11/12

  Time:     02:31:02 PM

  User:     N/A

  Computer: TERMINAL

  Description:

  Failed to initialize the needed name objects. Error Specifics: d:\xpsp\com\com1x\dtc\dtc\msdtcprx\src\dtcinit.cpp:215, 
  Pid: 3500

  No Callstack,
  CmdLine: C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllhost.exe /Processid:{02D4B3F1-FD88-11D1-960D-00805FC79235}

  Data:

  0000: 05 40 00 80               .@.`

The same issue will appear in the event log occur when trying to access the COM+ snap-in in the control panel.

The solution is to reinstall MSDTC by doing the following:
`net stop msdtc`
`msdtc -uninstall`
Delete the msdtc registry key
`msdtc -resetlogs`
`msdtc -install`
`net start msdtc`

This is on Windows XP Embedded SP 3.

What I am trying to find is the cause of the corruption of msdtc, but I am not sure where to start.

---

*Updates*

**(17/11)** The solution above, which reinstalls MSDTC, works in so that MSDTC is no longer corrupted and the machines can reconnect - however it does not correct the reconnection issue permanently. The machines can reconnect for a while (yet to determine how long or what changes) and then will fail - however without the MSDTC corruption this time.

**(18/11)** Testing the machines with a network connection, there issue never occurs. It would seem to indicate that the cause is something in the 3G modem.

**(19/11)** Tried upgrading the drivers to the latest versions with no change. Was also recommended to change the MTU to 1354, which has also not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something, unknown still, was wrong in the XPe image - likely from being resealed many times. A fresh XPe image from scratch resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like bad drivers to me. If you can't get newer drivers, try rolling back a version and see if the problem still remains. Sorry for not being anymore helpful than the obvious.

Comment: thanks for the idea - had the same idea yesterday and tried it and no luck with the latest drivers.